# MAC address problem (EEUPDATE)

Tags: ethernet

I've been trying to change my MAC address using eeupdate for my Intel Ethernet adapter for a while and all of a sudden it gave me an error: "Updating MAC Address to ... failed!". Does anybody know a fix?

This is what the error looks like:

[image]

Comment: Now the very first thing that pops to mind is "Why?" - this is extremely rarely necessary. The next thing is that you're not giving much information here. I found a similar posting from Intel's own forum: https://community.intel.com/t5/Embedded-Connectivity/I210-eeupdate-fails-to-program-MAC/m-p/693613. Maybe [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1776818/edit) your question using that as a template so there's some information that can be used to at least try to figure out what's failing. The OS version, exact commands, exact outputs are essential for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. The MAC address you are trying to program is BROADCAST MAC address (bit 0 in the leftmost byte is set). AFAIR the tool will prevent this as it is NOT a valid station address. Change the MAC address to valid station address and retry.
2. You've run out of OTP (one-time programmable) memory slots on a chip. There is no fix. I211 chips are targeted for consumer and embedded devices and have extremely limited configuration capabilities. All configuration settings, including MAC address are stored in OTP (one-time programmable) memory which has limited storage space. Every write takes one to a handful of slots which CANNOT be reused. In this case the only option is to programatically change the MAC address via driver settings.

DISCLOSURE: I work for Intel networking group.

Comment: So out of curiosity, do the consumer chips have capacity for at least one MAC address change, or none whatsoever? I'm planning to use EEUPDATE to fix the two motherboards we got with identical "88:88:88:88:87:88" MACs burned in.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to re-program MAC address a few times but I don't remember the details. AFAIR EEUPDATE has interactive mode and it should be possible to see the OTP content and evaluate how much is still left. Please remember that MAC address programming takes 3 DWORDs of OTP/iNVM.